# Isopropyl alcohol and water droplets

Tags: cpu, cleaning

I have a big container of 100% isopropyl alcohol that I purchased. I poured it in a small spray liquid bottle that used to have ethanol/propanol, which I cleaned with water. What I realized after doing that is that I poured it while the container had some droplets of water and I used the isopropyl from it to clean the cpu/fan from thermal paste. Are those droplets of water that remained going to be dissolved by the isopropyl alcohol or I should have dried it first? If it's not recommended, how likely is it that it damaged the components?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are those droplets of water that remained going to be dissolved by the isopropyl alcohol or I should have dried it first?

The IPA will be just slightly diluted with the water and contaminated with its impurities. If the amount of IPA was significantly larger than the amount of water, it's probably not a big deal.

> How likely is it that it damaged the components?

If you've used it just to clean off the IHS of the CPU (the metal cover on top) rather than the PCB or its edges, you're good. The radiator doesn't have any electrical components other than the fan, which you wouldn't have to wipe with the IPA, so it should be fine.

Comment: I'm no chemist, but I've always understood that the suspension of water in IPA is such that it speeds the drying of the water component too, hence the common use of 90% IPA with no lasting side effects.